# How to authorize a link based on role in Spring Security 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

I am trying to authorize a link based on role.

My page:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name==null}">
    <li> <a href="<c:url value="/registration"/>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Register</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="<c:url value="/login"/>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">Login</span></a> </li>    
</c:if>

<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name!=null}">

     <security:authorize access="ROLE_USER">
         <li><a href="cart.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">CART</span></a></li>
     </security:authorize>

     <li><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"></c:url>">logout</a></li>
</c:if>
```

I am getting following exception:

```
with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
    EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_USER' cannot be found on object of type 
    'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this..instead of `<security:authorize access="ROLE_USER">`

`<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a web-security expression, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#taglibs-authorize):

> **30.2 The authorize Tag**
>
> This tag is used to determine whether its contents should be evaluated or not. In Spring Security 3.0, it can be used in two ways [21]. The first approach uses a web-security expression, specified in the `access` attribute of the tag. The expression evaluation will be delegated to the `SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation>` defined in the application context (you should have web expressions enabled in your `<http>` namespace configuration to make sure this service is available). So, for example, you might have
>
> ```xml
> <sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">
>
>     This content will only be visible to users who have the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.
>
> </sec:authorize>
> ```

`ROLE_USER` is no built-in web-security expression (see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in)), use instead `hasRole('USER')`, see [`SecurityExpressionRoot#hasRole`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html#hasRole-java.lang.String-):

> Determines if the `SecurityExpressionOperations.getAuthentication()` has a particular authority within `Authentication.getAuthorities()`.
>
> This is similar to `SecurityExpressionOperations.hasAuthority(String)` except that this method implies that the String passed in is a role. For example, if "USER" is passed in the implementation may convert it to use "ROLE_USER" instead. The way in which the role is converted may depend on the implementation settings.